# How to fit html page in pop up window (dialogue box) without using scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I am newbie to JS/Html world and trying to load a html page in popup/dialog window on clicking some text in html but loaded page is bigger than poppup window size so there is scroll-bar.

**Javascript/Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.showModal2').click(function(){
      $('#popup2').dialog({width: 450,height: 450});
  });
});  

$(function(){
    $("#data").load("frontend/js/page.html"); 
});
```

**Html code**

```
<div id="popup2" title="Results" style="display:none;">          
     <div id="data" style="min-width: 200; height: 400; max-width:   400; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>  

<a HREF="javascript::void()" class="showModal2"><font color="blue">Link</font></a>
```

Is there any way to fit page within popup/dialog window size (here l=450 & b=450) completely without using scroll-bar like cropping page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

$(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: "auto"
            });
    $(".dialogify").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#dialog").html("");
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {
                    my: "center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: window
                });
    if ($("#dialog").dialog("isOpen") == false) {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                }
            });
        });

Answer (score -2):

Try this below code, it works for me:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
    });
    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

Comment: only difference in using "open" but i need dialog box to be of finite size and need to fit html page in that dialog box. How is it possible? Any working example will help me a lot.